# Conversion AAC+ to mp3

Tags: conversion

I listen a radio station in VLC Media Player. It broadcasts in AAC+ but I want to
listen it on my interneradio in MP3 format. How can I convert it into MP3 Stream?

Answer (score 0):

VLC can also convert the AAC+ broadcast to MP3 and broadcast it one again by RTSP, HTTP etc.
In VLC: Media > Stream... > Network > _your_aac_stream_ > Stream > and follow creator to stream out MP3.